# CSRF with REST API laravel

Tags: rest, laravel-5, csrf, dingo-api

I am new in laravel. I want to create REST API's with Laravel, I have used Dingo for it.
Now my problem is when I am sending post request

> CSRF token mismatch is error is throwing

and for web version we have used CSRF token for validating the request..

can anyone help me for solving CSRF token mismatch error in laravel 5.1.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: did you add the csrf_token() ?

Comment: if you want you can exclude specific url from CSRF verification.

Comment: Add the excluded URLs in this [file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/develop/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use CSRF tokens in an API. You should remove the middleware from `app/Http/Kernel.php` (on line 20) and use a different authentication method for your API.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have removed CSRF token and used jWT for token authentication

Comment: This is not the only answer to this question.  RESTful API's should be stateless is the general argument, but being stateless is not always more important than being secure.  This article is worth a read https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage

Comment: Also "Don't use CSRF tokens in an API" could use a reference.

Answer (score 8):

In your `app\http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php` file.

edit `$except` property with:

```
protected $except = [
  'yourapi/*' 
];
```

This will exclude your api routes from CSRF verification.And keep it up for other things like your frontend.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat related. So I am adding it for anyone else who comes across this page.
PostMan requests can also return the same issue. But you cannot implement the CSRF token the same way as you can on AJAX or within HTML and laravel side of the code. So here is a solution for PostMan requests.

Postman - "CSRF Token Mismatch" | Laravel REST API Tutorial
YOUTUBE : https://youtu.be/EgBq4IVnfnA

A useful article to support the video 
https://community.postman.com/t/get-body-variables-from-pre-request-script/8666

Answer (score -1):

You probably just aren't passing a CSRF-token in your API request to Laravel, causing the exception.

Comment: do you know how can I get CSRF token because I am using postman for sending post request

Comment: You could add a route that returns a CSRF token for you, but you should look into csrf exclusion for API routes.